# 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Tags: python, csv, influxdb-python

I need to present the result of the query from database in `csv` format using python.

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
client = InfluxDBClient(host='192.168.0.110', port=8086)
client.get_list_database()
client.switch_database('Mlogi_ALL')
res= client.query('SELECT * FROM n')
print(res)
```

The above line of codes retrieves the query result as:

> Out[5]: ResultSet({'(u'n', None)': [{u'sid': 3, u'time': u'2018-07-04T04:58:22Z', u'M': u'01081093', u'N': u'01081093', u'iid': u'0', u'V': 4, u'sd': u'0', u'ides': u'0'}, {u'sid': 3, u'time': u'2018-07-04T04:58:22Z', u'M': u'01081093', u'N': u'01081093', u'iid': None, u'V': 4, u'sd': None, u'ides': None}

Now I need these results in form of `csv`, so the next line of code is :

`res.to_csv("/home/rahul", sep=",", encoding="utf-8")`

But here I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       res.to_csv("/home/surya", sep=",", encoding="utf-8")
>
> AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

How to rectify this, I have seen few `ResultSet` errors on stackoverflow but I'm unable to retrieve my results to `csv` format.

Comment: [`ResultSet`](http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html#resultset) doesn't have a method for csv export

Comment: is there any alternative way to store the results of the query in csv or txt format ? @taras

Comment: There is `res.raw` attribute which returns a json object.